# Using a proxy server with fopen

Tags: php, proxy, stream, fopen

I'm trying to use fopen to read a remote file from another website. I want to use a proxy to do this, and as far as I know I can do:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://192.168.10.10:80' // The proxy server address and port
    ),
));

$file = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context)
```

but is there a way to authenticate using a username and password for that proxy? Or am I limited to having to use public proxies?

Also, the proxy definition is `tcp://192.168.10.10:80`. If I wanted to use a HTTP proxy, am I free to just change it to `http://192.168.10.10:80`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Proxy-Authorization](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.34) in the `$context` if the proxy requires authentication.Example from [**PHP.Net**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#111032):

```
$opts= array(
                 'http' => array( 
                 'proxy' => 'tcp://proxyip:8080', 
                 'header' => array( 
                                     "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth" 
                                  ) 
                ) 
); 
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

Also,I think you cannot change tcp to http in `tcp://192.168.10.10:80` since what the proxy does is establishing a TCP connection to another server on behalf of a client then route all the traffic back and forth between the client and the server.Obviously it concerns with TCP(sometimes UDP) instead of HTTP.Http proxies just "understand" the traffic delivered by HTTP protocol.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about sending a header with the request.